# Why does MediaPlayer use a SurfaceView even if I didn't specify it as display?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

Why does MediaPlayer output video on SurfaceView even though I didn't specify it as display? Am I missing something?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    TestVideoView2 v = new TestVideoView2(this);
    ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(v);
}

private static class TestVideoView2 extends  LinearLayout {

    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public TestVideoView2(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        try {
            surfaceView = new SurfaceView(getContext());
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            addView(surfaceView);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            //even though I specifically pointed to not use any display, I still get the video on the surface shown
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(null);
            //or any other source
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse("http://pmdvod.nationalgeographic.com/NG_Video/683/787/151026-news-microplastics-trash-trawl-vin-ds1502001-222__334712.mp4"));
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you don't create / add the SurfaceView?

Comment: @fadden then it doesn't output the video. I've noticed this behavior when I tried to create a "combined" VideoView (both with TextureView and SurfaceView). I decided to do it so a user can pick different aspect ratios with the best quality possible: if a video doesn't need to be larger than the screen, then SurfaceView is used (with aspect ratios 4:3, 16:9 and original), otherwise TextureView is used (when a video is stretched by the width and parts of height are cropped). I would use SurfaceView only if it could be larger than screen. I would use TextureView only if it had better scale mode.

Comment: You can find examples of adjusting the aspect ratio of both SurfaceView and TextureView for video playback in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika). The former uses an AspectFrameLayout class to alter the view size, the latter uses the TextureView transform matrix. A VideoView is SurfaceView + MediaPlayer, but a plain SurfaceView and a simple MediaPlayer instance don't really have any way to find each other, so I'm not sure how your MediaPlayer is magically finding your SurfaceView.